# Where should the volleyball hit your arms in a bump?

Tags: technique, volleyball

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOgfoEGUDCA) teaches how to pass through a volleyball bump. However, I noticed that the ball hits very close to the man's wrists, not much on his forearm.

Where should the ball be hit correctly on your arm, as to prevent blood spots and bruising? Can these be prevented with perfect form?

Answer (score 1):

The video you've linked to [answers this question itself at around the 3:17 mark](https://youtu.be/gOgfoEGUDCA?t=197):

> You want to contact the ball just above where you would wear a watch

Will this prevent bruising? No. Your forearms will toughen as you play regularly; if you take time off over the summer (or play beach with its lower pressure ball), you'll discover going back to the indoor ball at the start of the season probably does hurt for a bit, but it should go away after the first few practice sessions. If it doesn't, talk to your coach.